# Drawing circle arc in two colours with tikz: Centre gets shifted

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a circle with one half of the arc red and the other blue. I do get two arcs with my code but for some reason the centre of the second arc is not the same as the centre of the first:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (B) at (3, 0);
% Draw circle (polar coordinates):
%\draw [red] (0,0) arc [radius=3, start angle=230, end angle=320];
%\draw [blue] (0,0) arc [radius=3, start angle=320, end angle=230];

\draw [blue] (0,0) arc (0:180:3);
\draw [red] (0,0) arc (180:360:3);

\draw[fill=black] (B) circle (.1cm);
\node[label={[label distance=0cm]0:B}] at (B){};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result ist this:

[image]

Why is the centre shifted and how to draw two arcs around the same centre? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Is it okay now --

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (B) at (3, 0);
% Draw circle (polar coordinates):
%\draw [red] (0,0) arc [radius=3, start angle=230, end angle=320];
%\draw [blue] (0,0) arc [radius=3, start angle=320, end angle=230];

\draw [blue] (0,0) arc (0:180:3);
\draw [red] (0,0) arc (0:-180:3);

\draw[fill=black] (B) circle (.1cm);
\node[label={[label distance=0cm]0:B}] at (B){};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `\draw (0,0) arc (0:180:30);` (or the modern version `arc[start angle=0, end angle=180,radius=3]`)  imagine placing an invisible circle such that *the point of that circle which is at angle zero* (i.e. the right side of the circle) is at `(0,0)`, and then drawing counterclockwise along the circle.

Presumably you want to draw the circle around `B`? For a circle with radius 3 centered on `B`, the point at angle zero is at `(6,0)`, so you could use that as starting point of the arc: `\draw [blue] (6,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=3];`

If you start the arc at `(0,0)` you need `arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-180, radius=3]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (B) at (3, 0);
  
% Draw circle (polar coordinates):
\draw [red] (0,0)  arc [radius=3, start angle=180, delta angle=-180];
\draw [blue] (0,0) arc [radius=3, start angle=180, delta angle=180];

\draw[fill=black] (B) circle (.1cm) node[right=1mm] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```